# Defining a js-xlsx cell range

Tags: javascript, excel

I'm trying to read excel values using js-xlsx

I'm able to get a cell value from a workbook sheet using the following code

```
if(typeof require !== 'undefined') XLSX = require('xlsx');
var workbook = XLSX.readFile('test.xls');
var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
var sheet = sheet_name_list.indexOf('sheet_name');
var sheetF48 = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[sheet]]['F48'].v;
```

What I would like to do next is define a cell range so only those cell values are returned. I have figured out to get a sheet's ref by:

```
var sheet1 = workbook.Sheets[sheet_name_list[sheet_name]]
var range = XLSX.utils.decode_range(sheet1['!ref']);
```

Is it possible to define a cell range by providing the cell references?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I use the example (https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx#general-structures) but i add some code to get the values. 
`The mnemonic here is: s for "start of range", e for "end of range", r for "row", c for "column"`

```
var range = { s: { c: 0, r: 0 }, e: { c: 0, r: 4 } };//A1:A5
var dataRange = [];
/* Iterate through each element in the structure */
for (var R = range.s.r; R <= range.e.r; ++R) {
  for (var C = range.s.c; C <= range.e.c; ++C) {
    var cell_address = { c: C, r: R };
    var data = XLSX.utils.encode_cell(cell_address);
    dataRange.push(worksheet[data]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on the same problem all day.  I wasn't able to find a quick solution so if you did I would like to hear.  I did find a temporary fix. I had the two loops in different objects so they may be combined if wanted.

```
var cellStart = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c: colStart, r: rowStart});
var cellEnd = XLSX.utils.encode_cell({c: colEnd, r: rowEnd});
var dataRange = [];
var  z =   Object.keys(worksheet);
var i = z.indexOf(cellStart);
while (i!=z.indexOf(cellEnd) {
    dataRange.push(z[i]);
    i++;
    }
var desiredCells = {};
for (n of dataRange) {
    /* all keys that do not begin with "!" correspond to cell addresses */
    if (n[0] === '!') continue;
    desiredCells[n] = worksheet[n];
    }
```

Jade