# How to read particular column range row count in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel

I am working in excel import functionality in AngularJS. Now it's working fine by reading excel values. But I need read a particular column range row count
here I attached my tried code and expected output. Here I get row count as 7 but I need name and subject column row count only expected row count as 4 help how to solve this problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Angular Js XLS</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.9.13/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/angular-js-xlsx@0.0.3/angular-js-xlsx.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body ng-app="MyApp">

        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <js-xls onread="read" onerror="error"></js-xls>
            <!-- <input type="file" ng-change="read" onerror="error"> -->
        </div>

    </body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.module('MyApp', ['angular-js-xlsx'])
        .controller('myController', function($scope) {
            $scope.read = function (workbook) {
debugger;
                var headerNames = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json( workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]], { header: 1 })[0];
                var data = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json( workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]]);

                console.log(headerNames);
                console.log(data);

                for (var row in data)
                {
                    Object.keys(data[row]).forEach(function(key) {
                        console.log("Key = >" + key);
                        console.log("Value => " + data[row][key]);
                        console.log("===========================");
                    });
                }
            }

            $scope.error = function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    </script>

</html>
```

## Data

[image]

Comment: Looking here https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx there is a bullet point `encode_range / decode_range converts cell ranges`. So when I Googled 'js-xlsx range' I came up with this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383525/defining-a-js-xlsx-cell-range - So looks like a duplicate question perhaps. Hope it helps